# How do I prevent this access control SQL query from returning duplicates?

Tags: sql

We have a database with a table of Widgets. Each Widget can only be seen by a User with the right Role. Several Roles can be granted the right to see each Widget.

The tables looks like this:

**Widget**

```
Widget_Id
        1
```

**Permission**

```
Widget_Id | Role_Id
        1 |       1
        1 |       2
```

**Role**

```
Role_Id | User_Id
      1 |       1
      2 |       1
```

**User**

```
User_Id
      1
```

Now let's say I want to find all Widgets that a given user is allowed to see:

```
SELECT *
 FROM Widget
JOIN Permission USING(Widget_Id)
WHERE Role_Id IN (
  SELECT Role_Id
    FROM Role
    JOIN User
    WHERE User_Id = 1)
```

The problem here is that the Widget is granted to several Roles, and the User holds several Roles. How do I prevent the query from returning multiple duplicates of the same Widget, one for each Role? (Note that I don't want to use either `DISTINCT` nor the `ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTITION...)` trick. I've found the performance to degrade significantly for large tables).

Comment: You can simply  select Permission table with joins on Roles & Users, let this query return duplicate Widget_Id then put this query as subqery under select * from Widget  where Widget_Id in(yoursubquery).

Comment: If you don't want your sub query also to return duplicate Widget_Id's then you can put group by Widget_id in sub query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `WHERE EXISTS` construct. This guarantees that you will not see duplicate widgets.

```
SELECT * FROM Widget w
WHERE EXISTS
     (SELECT 1 FROM Permission p
      JOIN Role r ON r.Role_ID = p.Role_ID
      JOIN User u ON u.User_ID = r.User_ID
      WHERE p.Widget_ID = w.Widget_ID
      AND u.User_ID = ?)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your schema is like:

```
create table Widget (Widget_Id int, Widget_Name varchar(50));
create table Permission (Widget_Id int,Role_Id int);
Create table Roles (Role_Id int, [User_Id] int);
Create table Users ([User_Id] int, [User_Name] varchar(50));
go
```

And data sample is as below:

```
insert into WIDGET Values(1, 'W1');
insert into WIDGET Values(2, 'W2');
insert into PERMISSION Values(1,1);
insert into PERMISSION Values(1,2);
Insert into ROLES Values(1,1);
Insert into ROLES Values(2,1);
Insert into USERS Values(1,'U1');
Insert into USERS Values(2,'U2');
Go
```

The script to give you single set of allowed widgets for given user would be:

```
SELECT *
 FROM Widget W
WHERE W.WIDGET_ID   IN (
  SELECT P.WIDGET_ID
    FROM Roles R
    JOIN Permission P on R.ROLE_ID=P.ROLE_ID
    JOIN Users U ON R.USER_ID=U.USER_ID
    WHERE U.User_Id = 1)
```